# Couldn't create laravel project with composer (version 2.1.4)

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to [create a laravel project with composer](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#installation-via-composer) and when I run

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app
```

in the terminal, the process stops with the following error:

```
[RuntimeException]
php: does not exist and could not be created.
```

I have php 7.4 running through Wampserver and I've added it's PATH to the environment variables and when I run php -v in the terminal, everything seems fine:

```
PHP 7.4.0 (cli) (built: Nov 27 2019 10:14:18) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

what am I missing here? I'm using composer version 2.1.4 and running the command in administrative mode didn't make a difference neither.

[screenshot of running commands on the command-line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJZOa.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update to version 2.1.5 of Composer by running this command:

```
composer self-update
```

This was [a bug](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/10020) that has since been fixed. It was attempting to create a directory called `php:` which is not possible on Windows systems.